# Method listIndividual() takes more than 15 mins with "DBPedia_2014.owl" (2MB-size file)

Tags: java, jena, owl, dbpedia

"dbpedia_2014.owl" is an owl file organizing different concepts, which contains no individual.
It can be download by http://data.dws.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/dbpedia/2014/dbpedia_2014.owl.bz2

The thing is when I use listIndividual() method in Jena, **it took more than 15 minutes to handle such a small size(2MB) file.** The code is below:

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class OntModelTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName1 = new String("owl_qiwang_test/vc-db-1.rdf");
        String fileName2 = new String("owl_qiwang_test/dbpedia_2014.owl");

        OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();

        ontModel.read(fileName2);

        long startMil = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Start: " + startMil);

        ontModel.listIndividuals();

        long endMil = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Duration: " + (endMil - startMil));

    }
}
```

I'm wondering why it takes such a long time to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for the method you're using says that it provides some reasoning capabilities. This is likely to be the origin of performance issues, as complexity of reasoning is not strongly linked to size: larger ontologies are usually harder to reason with than smaller ontologies, however it is possible for small ontologies to be really hard to reason with.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory.html#createOntologyModel--

> ```
> public static OntModel createOntologyModel()
> ```
>
> Answer a new ontology model which will process in-memory models of ontologies expressed the default ontology language (OWL). The default document manager will be used to load the ontology's included documents.
>
> Note:The default model chosen for OWL and RDFS includes a weak reasoner that includes some entailments (such as transitive closure on the sub-class and sub-property hierarchies). Users who want either no inference at all, or alternatively more complete reasoning, should use one of the other createOntologyModel methods that allow the preferred OntModel specification to be stated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63661603/how-to-clone-a-jena-ontmodel-to-another-with-a-different-modelspec/63667275#63667275)

If you want to use the `listIndividuals()` method without using a reasoner, you can do:

```
  Model _model = model.getRawModel();
  OntModel newModel = new OntModelImpl(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, _model);
```